# ajax second call: function is not a function error

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

When I click #submit-login button first time. The ajax call is successful. However, on clicking the same button a second time, I am hit with the error:
Uncaught TypeError: userLogin is not a function

HTML:

```
            <input id="username" type="username" name="" placeholder="Username">
            <input id="password" type="password" name="" placeholder="Password"><br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-login"> Login</button>
```

JS File Linked to HTML Page

```
    $("#submit-login").on("click", function(){
    userLogin();
    });
function userLogin(){
    userLogin = $("#username").val();
    userPass = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'controllers/login.php',
            data: {
                'username': userLogin,
                'password' : userPass
            },
            success: function(responseText) {
                console.log(responseText);
            }
        });
};
```

PHP File

```
<?php
$savedUser = "irexjr";
$savedPass = "1234";

$request_user = $_POST['username'];
$request_password = $_POST['password'];

$loginsuccess = "";

if(($request_user == $savedUser) && ($request_password == $savedPass)){
    echo 1;
}
else{
    echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: The function `userLogin()` creates a global variable with the same name. After calling `userLogin()` it is no longer a function but a string (the username)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the other commentators are trying to tell you is the following:
You declare a function `userLogin()` in global scope. Now you run the function and inside the function body you declare another variable `userLogin` without using var, let or const causing the variable to end up in global scope as well overwriting the one already there -> the function. So you have several options:

1. rewrite the function as @TechBreak already proposed
2. rename the function as @Thomas Charlesworth proposed
3. declare the variables inside the function body using var, let or
   const to put them in function scope

In any case: Never ever declare variables without var, let or const. Otherwise they will end up in global scope causing errors that might be difficult to track down.

Answer (score 1):

Try following, variable defined are created in global scope and as pointed in comment it has same name as function and further they are not required it seems.

```
function userLogin(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'controllers/login.php',
            data: {
                'username': $("#username").val(),
                'password' : $("#password").val()
            },
            success: function(responseText) {
                console.log(responseText);
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function userLogin() creates a global variable with the same name. After calling userLogin() it is no longer a function but a string (the username)

As posted by @Andreas

Changed Function name to resolve.